# Why isnt my font options dropping down when I click a text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I am using Adobe Illustrator 2017 and when I use my selection tool to click text I dont see the font name come up near where the character and paragraph buttons normally are. The only way I can see the font name and change the font is if I click character. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your screen is just too small to show all menus? Probably the menu bar could be arranged differently.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using a 13" laptop or similar. The interface adapts to smaller screens and some panels get collapsed into simple buttons. To reach the font name you need to click the **Character** link just above your question mark, which is normally expanded and visible on displays over 15".

Answer (score 1):

On the right side of the Menu Bar is a pull down menu where you can switch on/off some of the entries. If you just switch off `Transform` which might give you enough space to show you the full text tools. `Transform` can easily be accessed via `Window > Transform`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have **Character** ticked in the dock options dropdown? You appear to have plenty of space in your dock to allow the Character options to appear.

[image]